# table view memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have some memory issues using table view in iOS.

I have a screen setup like this [image] , so there is one View Controller going to another with table view.

Every time I go in the controller with table view and go back my memory keeps incrementing by about 1 MB.

So memory usage gets big in a few screen changes 
[image]

Any ideas to why this is happening?

Thanks

Code for the view controller with table view:

view did load method:

```
 questionGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"databaseApp.sql"];

sqlite3 *database = NULL;
 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){


  const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM question_groups";
     sqlite3_stmt *statement;
     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){


         while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

             NSMutableArray *questionType = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

             NSString *groupName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
             NSString *groupId = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

             [questionType addObject:groupId];
             [questionType addObject:groupName];

             [questionGroups addObject:questionType];

             questionType = nil;

         }


         sqlite3_finalize(statement);
         statement = nil;
     }

     sqlite3_close(database);

 }
database = NULL;

//populiranje liste
self.table.delegate = self;
self.table.dataSource = self;
```

cell creating:

```
static NSString *CellIndentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier];

if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIndentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

NSInteger row = indexPath.row;


cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",questionGroups[row][0],questionGroups[row][3]];
```

Comment: Using `Instrument`, `Memory Leak`, which line is shown to be leaking?

Comment: as far as i know, the memory usage monitor in xcode displays the cumulative memory usage and not your current memory usage, it is quite misleading, you will need to use instruments to keep track of your current memory usage. it is still useful to see the jumps in memory usage to see if there is something drastically wrong

Comment: Tnx for your reply's, not realy sure how to use instruments, but whenever i switch views the graph in Alocations tab jumps for 2MB?

Comment: Allocation are normal. It doesn't mean that they aren't correctly deallocated (so that they don't create memory leak).

Comment: So I shouldnt be worried about that someone could do this 100 times and would fill the memory?

Comment: What kind of transitions are the segue's using?

Comment: Cross dissolve transition